# AutoTrain advanced CLI: error: unrecognized arguments: --fp16 --use-int4

Tags: python, machine-learning, large-language-model, peft

I am currently facing an issue while fine-tuning my data with the LLM model in a Colab notebook using the provided autotrain tool. The error message suggests that the arguments '--fp16' and '--use-int4' are not recognized by autotrain. I've checked the documentation and syntax, but the problem persists. Could you provide guidance on resolving this issue or offer insights into any potential solutions? Thank you.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:13:
 UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torchvision/image.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3c104cuda9SetDeviceEi'If you don't plan on using image functionality from`torchvision.io`, you can ignore this warning. Otherwise, there might be something wrong with your environment. Did you have `libjpeg`or`libpng`installed before building`torchvision` from source?   warn( usage: autotrain <command> [<args>] AutoTrain advanced CLI: error: unrecognized arguments: --fp16 --use-int4
```

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt33r.png)

this code was working fine till yesterday on the colab notebook given in this [https://github.com/huggingface/autotrain-advanced](https://stackoverflow.com) repo for fine tuning LLM, Now getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this
quantization int4 and --mixed-precision fp16
this will solve your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer is in `autotrain llm  --help`. It's a long list but the info is there:

Comment: The answer is in `autotrain llm  --help`. It's a long list but the info is there (for version 0.6.86):

```bash
  usage: autotrain <command> [<args>] llm [-h] [--text_column TEXT_COLUMN]
  ...
    --quantization QUANTIZATION, --quantization QUANTIZATION
                          int4, int8, or None
  ...
    --mixed-precision MIXED_PRECISION, --mixed-precision MIXED_PRECISION, --mp MIXED_PRECISION
                          fp16, bf16, or None
  ...
```

(unable to edit the comment above, took too long, here is the comment above with more details..Oh well the format does not work.)

Answer (score -1):

Clone the Google Collab notebook again and execute as there was a code change that caused the old way of passing parameters to break.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).